# Range of convergence and uniformly convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For what range of positive x is 
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^{n}} $convergent and uniformly convergent?

I try to use ratio test for 
convergence. But my ratio test does not work.

And I try weierstrass test for uniform convergence, but I cannot find the upper bound for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Try the comparison

$$
\frac{1}{1 + x^n} < \frac{1}{x^n} \quad\forall x > 0
$$

If $0 < x \leq 1$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^n} \neq 0$, and hence the series diverges by the divergence test. Using this comparison you should be able to prove uniform convergence on any interval of the form $[\alpha,\infty)$ for $\alpha > 1$.

Comment: This should help in proving convergence. But not uniform convergence. Can you give me more hints on uniform convergence? Thanks.

Comment: The inequality gives you the comparison to make. The series does not converge for all positive x. Use the Weierstrass M-test to prove uniform convergence.

Comment: @tony1 You do realize the actual question is missing, in the body of the question? Adding it  may help people to answer (or to search for relevant questions on the website, in the future).

Comment: @ClementC I completely agree with you. The question is incomplete and I am trying to infer what is being asked.